# Best pratice : how to make a good class in php

Tags: php, class

1. I would like to improve my php web development, so, i would like to know what is your best pratice when you make a new object class ?
2. I have a sample of a class object. I would like to know how do you do this. If it's good or bad.

---

```
  Class Contact extends Object {

    public $id;

    public $firstname = 'john';

    public $lastname = 'doe';

    public function __construct($id_contact = NULL) {

            parent::__construct($id_contact);


        if ($this->id) {

                $this->fullname = $this->firstname . ' '.$this->lastname
            }
        }
        public static function getFullName($id_contact){

            $cnt = new Contact($id_contact);
            return $cnt->fullname;
        }

        }
```

And use the method like this in different controller :

```
$cnt_fullname = Contact::getFullName($id);
```

Or it's better to load new object in the controller

```
$cnt = new Contact($id);
$cnt_fullname = $cnt->fullname;
```

Thanks you for your reply.

Comment: What is the sense behind the first variant? Sounds pretty useless to me, since it can only access statically implemented properties.

Comment: the sense behind the first variant is to avoid to do 2 lines on controller

Comment: you function __construct not ending `}`

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there. Saving a single line is not an improvement.

Comment: ok, so for you, the best way is to second variant and the first variante is not interessting.

Comment: Just a thought: Shouldn't this question be asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of asking it here, since that is meant for taking the review on the code written, how the code can be improved etc. etc. ??

Comment: First time on stackoverflow, sorry, i don't see codereview.stackexchange..

Comment: If you really want to avoid the 2 lines you can also do `(new Contact)->getFullName($id)`

Comment: But if you really want to write good OOP code, take a look at this: http://www.php-fig.org/ and http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: i never see your syntax CodeBrauer, thanks. And thanks all for your reply. I will read phptherightway.com (don't know this site before...)

So, now, i can say, that the first variante is not specially good to do..

Answer (score 1):

The way I make good classes:

```
class Good
{
}
```

Comment: not my question but thank you for your interest...

Comment: google for "design patterns php" and "psr coding standards" for a kick start

Comment: the best answer :D

Answer (score 0):

So, for example best way

```
    class Getter {

       private static $contact = null   

       public static function getContactObj($id) {
          if(!is_null(self::$contact)) {
             return self::$contact;
          }
          self::$contact = new Contact($id);
          return self::$contact;
       }
    }
```

and your class contact

```
    Class Contact extends Object {

        public $id;

        public $firstname = 'john';

        public $lastname = 'doe';


        public function setId($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getFullName()
            $this->fullname = $this->firstname . ' '.$this->lastname
            return $this->fullname;
        }

  }
```

And you can use this construction in over controllers:

```
Getter::getContactObj()
        ->setId(1)
        ->getFullName();

Getter::getContactObj()
        ->setId(2)
        ->getFullName();

Getter::getContactObj()
        ->setId(3)
        ->getFullName();
```

and etc.

Comment: hmmm... interessting... thank you.